# What could cause "Access denied" when trying to access my own MySQL on Windows?

Tags: windows, mysql

I just installed MySQL on my WinXP machine. I try to login and get this:

```
$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p my_database
Enter password: ************
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I created a database `my_database` in the MySQL GUI with the correct username and password. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, got it, I needed to set a password like this:

```
mysqladmin -u root password my_password
```

Comment: The issue you ran into was probably because you specified the `-p` argument on the command line, which prompts you for a password. If you hadn't set a password during install, then the password would have been blank, and you could have accessed it via `mysql -u root my_database`